# Figure out if element is present in multi-dimensional array in python

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am parsing a log containing nicknames and hostnames. I want to end up with an array that contains the hostname and the latest used nickname.

I have the following code, which only creates a list over the hostnames:

```
hostnames = []

# while(parsing):
#    nick = nick_on_current_line
#    host = host_on_current_line 

if host in hostnames:
    # Hostname is already present.
    pass
else:
    # Hostname is not present
    hostnames.append(host)

print hostnames
# ['foo@google.com', 'bar@hotmail.com', 'hi@to.you']
```

I thought it would be nice to end up with something along the lines of the following:

```
# [['foo@google.com', 'John'], ['bar@hotmail.com', 'Mary'], ['hi@to.you', 'Joe']]
```

My problem is finding out if the hostname is present in such a list

```
hostnames = []

# while(parsing):
#    nick = nick_on_current_line
#    host = host_on_current_line   

if host in hostnames[0]: # This doesn't work.
    # Hostname is already present.
    # Somehow check if the nick stored together 
    # with the hostname is the latest one
else:
    # Hostname is not present
    hostnames.append([host, nick])
```

Are there any easy fix to this, or should I try a different approach? I could always have an array with objects or structs (if there is such a thing in python), but I would prefer a solution to my array problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a dictionary instead.

```
names = {}

while(parsing):
    nick = nick_on_current_line
    host = host_on_current_line   

    names[host] = nick
```

Comment: Wow. A lot easier than I expected. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Use a [dictionary](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict) instead of a list. Use the hostname as the key and the username as the value.

Comment: A dict will do all you need.  Repeated updates for the same host will only keep the last value, and accessing dict.items() will give back the array of host->nick entries.

Answer (score 2):

```
if host in zip(*hostnames)[0]:
```

or

```
if host in (x[0] for x in hostnames):
```

Comment: Testing for membership in a set or dict is far more scaleable than testing within a list, especially for so nicely hashable an item as a hostname string.